# Add a directory in a url

Tags: path

I want to add a button in this url
`https://2022.ibaiarte.com/listing/intersport-loramendi-garibai/`
with this link `https://2022.ibaiarte.com/es/listing/intersport-loramendi-garibai/` (the same url with the **es/** directory before the path)

I used this code, but **/es** directory isn't displayed:

```
document.getElementById("enlace").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var urlActual = "2022.ibaiarte.com/es"+window.location.pathname;
   window.location.hostname = urlActual;
});
```

Comment: Please include the language tag to your question.